# Maximum and mean lengths of streaks/runs of identical responses

Tags: r

We have a dataset with ID numbers in the first column and then responses to each of 240 questions in the following 240 columns. We'd like to assess the validity of the responses for each subject by finding the maximum and mean of the lengths of streaks or runs of identical responses. For example, if a subject responded `(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1)` to ten questions, the maximum would be 4 and the mean would be 2.5.

I have tried to solve this problem in R using `rle()`, but after I apply `rle()` to every row of the data frame I can't extract the lengths. Once I extract the lengths, I think it would be relatively easy to apply `max()` and `mean()`. Any help or advice on getting to that point would be appreciated.

There are two more issues that are minor and don't necessarily need to be answered here. The first is that it would be even more informative to find the maximum and mean per response (there are five possible responses, namely, 1 through 5). In the example above, the maxima and means for 1, 2, and 5 would be, respectively, 3 and 2, 2 and 2, and 4 and 4. The second is that I don't know how to apply `rle()` to the 240 responses exclusively, i.e. and not also to the ID number. I've been deleting the ID number column before manipulating the data frame in R, which is fine, but will lead to error if I unintentionally rearrange the rows.

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you have completely randomized the response numbers for each question--which is almost never done, because responses are often on an ordered scale so the order cannot be broken--then it seems that runs of identical responses won't tell you anything at all about validity.

Comment: If a subject gives the same response to all 240 questions, it's an indication that he or she did not think about his or her responses, and thus his or her responses are not valid. Our reasoning is that a subject could give identical responses to a long string of questions (but not necessarily all 240) and that would also be an indication of invalid responses, particularly if there are multiple long strings. This is also the reasoning behind the "random responding" validity check of the NEO Five Factor personality questionnaire.

Comment: Fine--but there is no statistical basis for identifying a cutoff in run lengths that identifies "nonthinking" responses.  In fact, very long run lengths could just mean the responses offered to the questions offer little discrimination.  Normally the way one detects thoughtless responses is by including sets of questions whose answers are closely related but should be different in order to be consistent, such as negating an earlier question later in the survey.

Comment: That is a good way to detect thoughtless responses, but questions of that type are not included in this measure and we can't rewrite it or re-administer it to our participants. There may not be a statistical basis for identifying a cutoff using this measure alone, but there is also no statistical basis for identifying a cutoff using the PTSD Checklist or Beck Depression Inventory alone, either. Cutoffs are identified because they are predictive, and we have other measures with their own validity checks that may be predicted by maximum run length. At the very least, can't we identify outliers?

Comment: Yes, identifying outliers is a good approach in any event. You can look both at run lengths and numbers of runs.  But expect complications from skewness in the run length distribution: I suspect looking for outliers in the logarithms of the run lengths would be more helpful.

Comment: Very good points. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `rle` function returns a list, but this is not immediately obvious because it is possible to make R print whatever you want when you type the name of an object and the authors of `rle` have made it print something else. In order to find out the structure of an object, you can use `str`, for example

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1)
codes <- rle(x)
str(codes)
```

You can get at the lengths by typing `codes$lengths` and similarly for the corresponding values.

Anyway, notwithstanding the statistical issues, here is how to do what you want. Suppose you have 30 subjects and they have responded to eight questions. Your data might look like this

```
set.seed(123)
repsonses <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5, 8*30, replace=T), nc=8))

> head(responses)
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1  3  2  4  2  4  1  1  5
2  1  5  2  1  5  3  1  1
3  1  3  1  2  3  5  5  3
4  4  4  5  3  4  2  4  2
5  5  5  2  5  3  1  2  4
6  3  3  3  3  1  1  3  2
```

You can extract the maximum lengths of the runs for each subject like this:

```
> max.lengths <- apply(responses, 1, function(x) max(rle(x)$lengths))
> max.lengths
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 4 3 1 1 2 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
```

The max length was 2 for the first 5 subjects and 4 for the sixth subject, so it looks right.

Similarly for the mean lengths

```
> mean.lengths <- apply(responses, 1, function(x) mean(rle(x)$lengths))
> head(mean.lengths)
[1] 1.142857 1.142857 1.142857 1.142857 1.142857 2.000000
```

For example, the mean length for the first person was the mean of $1,1,1,1,1,2,1$ which is $8/7$, which agrees with what R says.

To break down the whole thing by response, you can use the same ideas and the `tapply` function like this:

```
bd <- function(x){
    means <- tapply(x$lengths, factor(x$values,levels=0:5), mean)
    means[is.na(means)] <- 0
    maxes <- tapply(x$lengths, factor(x$values,levels=0:5), max)
    maxes[is.na(maxes)] <- 0
    M <- rbind(means, maxes)
    rownames(M) <- c("mean", "max")
    M
}

lapply(apply(responses, 1, rle), bd)
```

This outputs another list. For example, if you scroll up, you will see that for subject 25, it says

```
[[25]]
     0 1 2 3 4 5
mean 0 1 2 1 0 2
max  0 1 2 1 0 2
```

compare with

```
> responses[25,]
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
25  3  5  5  3  2  2  1  3
```

so it is giving the correct answer. You can give this list a name, for example

```
break.downs <- lapply(apply(responses, 1, rle), bd)
```

and then you can access the entry for subject `i` by typing

```
break.downs[[i]]
```

For the problem with the ID number column, if it's included, say as column 1, you can just do the whole analysis to `responses[ ,-1]` and that should be OK. The $-1$ just deletes the first column.

PS. Sorry, I just noticed that I did it with repsonses $0$ to $5$ instead of $1$ to $5$, but you just need to change `levels=0:5` to `levels=1:5` in the `bd` function and it should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am partial to the `data.table` package.  To use it, first reshape to long format.  Then use `rle` (making sure to take the first list element of the result, using `[[1]]`), take the max/mean, and group by the respondent ID.

Here is an example with five respondents and 10 questions:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(8028)

responses <- data.frame(cbind(id=1:5,matrix(sample(1:5, 10*5, replace=T), nc=10)))
responses
#   id V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
# 1  1  3  4  2  5  1  2  4  4   1   3
# 2  2  2  2  4  5  5  2  3  3   3   1
# 3  3  5  1  3  3  4  4  1  4   2   2
# 4  4  3  2  4  5  2  2  1  4   1   3
# 5  5  5  2  4  5  3  1  4  1   2   4

responses.long<-data.table(reshape(responses, idvar="id", varying=list(2:11), direction="long"),key=c("id","time"))

responses.long[,list(run=max(rle(V2)[[1]]), mean=mean(rle(V2)[[1]])), by="id"]
#    id run     mean
# 1:  1   2 1.111111
# 2:  2   3 1.666667
# 3:  3   2 1.428571
# 4:  4   2 1.111111
# 5:  5   1 1.000000
```

Wouldn't this question by more appropriate for StackOverflow?

Comment: I'm really sorry, when I enter `library(data.table)` I get an error message saying that there is no such package. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `data.table` is an add-on package (not part of base R), so you have to install it first.  The `library` command just loads it.  Consult the documentation if you're not sure how to install a package.